# How to create instance of component definition class in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, oop

I am new in angular 4 and I am learning it day by day using tutorials but I am not understanding after a lot of research that how to create an instance of component class.

This is the sample code that I am following

```
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {
 name: string; // <-- added name property

   constructor() {
    this.name = 'Felipe'; // set the name
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

}
```

I am rendering this component /user-item.component.html like this

```
<p>
 Hello {{ name }}
</p>
```

and then /app.component.html file

```
<app-user-item></app-user-item>
```

It displays the name "Felipe" correctly but I am not understanding that how It is working. I know about constructor is calling when the instance is creating but I don't know which one is the instance in the below?

```
<app-user-item></app-user-item>
{{ name }}
```

I know oop concepts very well but in angular I am still confuse about its terms and flow. Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: try reading this: https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Comment: @methgaard thanks for your reply. I have read this but it is written according to hero editor and I am not following hero editor. I am just following simple approach.Can you please answer me according to my question?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is the question. It is titled "How to create instance of component definition class in angular 4?" - angular does it for you when you use "<app-user-item></app-user-item>". Then you have "I know about constructor is calling when the instance is creating but I don't know which one is the instance in the below?" which isn't really a question, in general, every time you have "<app-user-item></app-user-item>" in your html, angular creates the new instance of the component.

Comment: Why is the question not clear? One main aspect of oop is to define classes and instantiate objects accordingly. The objects have methods (defined in the class) to communicate with the rest of the program, e.g. with simple getters or setters. In angular the templates seemingly directly interact with the class variables (bad practice), as one never touches the instance. However, I know about [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), but this is certainly not the idea behind oop. For me it seems like Angular developers failed to implement this property of oop. Or?

Answer (score 0):

@Antikhippe when your app get load, it rend a view which is app.component.html. In your case that View is rendering another View "" which has this piece of code "

Hello {{ name }}

"
when angular see the {{ ...}} it knows that you are referencing a property that is available in the component most of the time the .ts. That concept is what angular call "Data binding". 
you can create a class in a separate file (.ts) within the component folder , import the class in the component class and instantiate an object of the class just like in java : "this.model = new SubjectInfo();" 
"this" has the same meaning like in all OOP it reference the property of the component class. 
"SubjectInfo" is the class that I imported in my component class.
I hope that help.